# SBT can't read environment variables in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, rc

I defined a new environment variable in `~/.zshrc` like that: `export JVM_XMX=-Xmx2048M`. I can verify that it was set correctly running `export` command and finding it in the list.

Now I want to use it in SBT. I've tried these two approaches:

`sys.env("JVM_XMX")`

`sys.env.get("JVM_XMX")`

But the value couldn't be found or the `Option` is `None`. Errors that I see are:

`NoSuchElementException: key not found: JVM_XMX`

`NoSuchElementException: None.get`

What I also tried was to add the variable into SBT in IntelliJ Settings. I went to `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `sbt` and set `VM parameters` to `-DJVM_XMX=-Xmx2048M`. It didn't help.

Anyone knows how to setup SBT to work with IntelliJ correctly?

---

Versions used:

sbt 1.2.8

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I was able to use system properties (`scala.sys.SystemProperties`). This works because this is the way how to find values added into SBT in IntelliJ Settings.

Code example from `build.sbt`:

`sys.props.get("JVM_XMX")`

**UPDATE:**

I was finally able to figure out what was the real problem. My `.bashrc` file was incorrectly set up (I had the variables only in `.zshrc`). After adding environment variables into correct `rc` file, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like this property to be part of your project, and not only in your solution, you can add a file names ".sbtopts" at the root of your repository, next to the build.sbt file.
In this file you can configure the JVM options.
For instance you can add there:
-J-Xmx2048M

I couldn't find the sbt documentation supporting my suggestion, but it works for me :)

Comment: Looks like this should work for JVM options. But how to define custom environment variable? I've tried `-DCUSTOM_VARIABLE=value`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by going to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> sbt, then enabling sbt shell for builds and project reload.

[image: intellij sbt shell use for settings]